# How do i make this code less repetitive? Random password generator

Tags: python, performance

I'm making a random password generator in Python, it takes a template from the user and the number of passwords and creates random passwords that adhere to that template.

Right now it works as intended which is fine, but it has 4 if statements that do basically the same thing, but i'm not sure how to make it less repetitive.

Here's what i have -

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random, sys, string

digit = string.digits
lower = string.lowercase
upper = string.uppercase
symbol = string.punctuation


if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print 'error, not enough arguments, need a template and the number of passwords'
    print 'ex: ./passgen Template1! 100'

else:
    passlist =[]
    template = sys.argv[1]

    for j in range(0,int(sys.argv[2])): 
        password = ''
        charSet = ''
        for i in template: #runs through every character in the template provided by the user and checks what each character is and adds the appropriate string constants to the character set
            if i.islower():
                charSet += lower
                password += charSet[random.randint(0,len(charSet)-1)]
                charSet = ''
            elif i.isupper():
                charSet += upper
                password += charSet[random.randint(0,len(charSet)-1)]
                charSet = ''
            elif i.isdigit():
                charSet += digit
                password += charSet[random.randint(0,len(charSet)-1)]
                charSet = ''
            elif i in string.punctuation:
                charSet += symbol
                password += charSet[random.randint(0,len(charSet)-1)]
                charSet = ''    

        passlist.append(password)

print passlist
```

I don't like that i'm doing this action

```
            password += charSet[random.randint(0,len(charSet)-1)]
            charSet = ''
```

for every if statement, it seems redundant, but i don't know any other way to do it.

Example input and output -

```
./passgen.py Password1! 10
['Hozxmtll1*', 'Grprwixi2,', 'Fwqarvcu5.', 'Ikfywvth6_', 'Sndcnecv3&', 'Pkeerxpm0(', 'Tjiliflo5@', 'Ibftiisa8_', "Xiljjsss8'", 'Ukfupsri6]']
```

Comment: Can you explain (edit your question for this) exactly how you're trying to generate a password? That is, what are the inputs, what are the expected outputs? Hopefully, you're also not using this to generate actual passwords.

Comment: @pvg I'm learning pen testing so the end goal is to make a program that does a dictionary attack. added example input and output in the main post

Comment: You should describe the intended process by which you want to generate the password.

Comment: there is a module that can generate strings matching a regex i forgot the name but try to google this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `i` always matches any of the given conditions (if not, put `else:continue` under the last `elif` block).

```
for i in template: #runs through every character in the template provided by the user and checks what each character is and adds the appropriate string constants to the character set
    if i.islower():
        charSet += lower
    elif i.isupper():
        charSet += upper
    elif i.isdigit():
        charSet += digit
    elif i in string.punctuation:
        charSet += symbol

    password += charSet[random.randint(0,len(charSet)-1)]
    charSet = ''
```

Simple as that. BTW: creating passwords with pseudo-random numbers is extremely insecure.

P.S.: It works like charm for me:

```
$ python2 /tmp/pytest.py "sfid!" 5
['eqeu-', 'uztv,', "qxdg'", 'mahe+', 'wvsn[']
```

Comment: That's what i did earlier, but it doesn't work correctly. it doesn't match the template that i give it, it seems to just produce random strings in the length of the template. I'm making this to eventually make a program that does a dictionary attack, i'm not using these passwords

Comment: It is a consequence of logic that if two lines of code that are executed regardless of any disjunct condition, they can be moved outside of an if-else block. Therefore these two programs must behave the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your character sets in a list and select the matching item if any.

```
charsets = [string.digits, string.lowercase, string.uppercase, string.punctuation]
passlist =[]
template = sys.argv[1]

for j in range(0, int(sys.argv[2])): 
    password = ''
    for i in template: 
        charset = [cs for cs in charsets if i in cs]
        if charset:
            charset = charset[0] 
            password += charset[random.randint(0, len(charset)-1)]
    passlist.append(password)
```

If the character is not part of any item in `charsets` the loop moves to the next character without modifying `password` but you could set a default value instead, if you want it to have a fixed length.

Also i think it would be better if you wrap the random string generator in a small function.

```
def pass_gen(template):
    password = ''
    charsets = [string.digits, string.lowercase, string.uppercase, string.punctuation]
    for i in template: 
        charset = [cs for cs in charsets if i in cs]
        if charset:
            charset = charset[0] 
            password += charset[random.randint(0, len(charset)-1)]
    return password
```